# Count number of whitespaces in a character string in c

Tags: c, character, whitespace

```
#include <stdio.h>                  

int main (){
int d=0;                          
int e;                           
while ((e=getchar())!=EOF)  {   
if(e==' '){ 
d++;
}
if(e=='\n')
return 0;
printf("%d",d);

}
}
```

When i run this code if i type in "hello sir how are you" as my input string, the result i get is 000001111222233334444.. obviously there are 4 whitespace characters, how do i get my code to print out 4 instead of counting the number of whitespaces for every character entered

Comment: Change the `return` to `break` and move the `printf` outside the `while` loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You placed `printf("%d",d);` inside the `while` loop. Place it outside it to print the aggregate number of spaces.
And finally change `return 0` to `break`, otherwise it will terminate the program without executing the last statement `printf("%d",d);`.

Comment: And change the `return` to `break`.